# VBA - RemoveAllDuplicateButOne()

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, delete-row

I have a data sheet with 18000 customers. Around 10% of this list are duplicates of the same customer sometimes they are duplicated more than once.

I'd like to use VBA to find all duplicates and remove the WHOLE ROW of data; leaving one only one data row (1 customer) left.

I come across this code online:

```
Sub RemoveAllDuplicateButOne()
    Dim LR As Long: LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LR).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=Name
End Sub
```

However, this VBA code will only remove a remove duplicates in row A and will delete the column and as such move the column from the row below into the column space that's just been deleted. Meaning you have all sorts of customers data mixing.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work for me:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:W1800").RemoveDuplicates
Columns:=Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19), Header:=xlYes
```

The columns I can use for identifiers are Column A (IP address), Coumn G (email Address), Column H (Phone Number). Ideally, I'd like to run the VBA first using column G, then H, then A.

To clarify I'd like to delete the whole row of an identified duplication.

I'm sorry if this seems a silly question or perhaps complex I'm not sure but I have searched around and I am unable to find an answer. Any help would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use Excel remove duplicates functionality?

Comment: Tried that and it only removes the duplicated column, not the entire row. The column from below the remove duplication column moves into its position leaving you with a contaminated row.

Comment: Remove duplicates don't remove columns! If you select entire rows, entire rows will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to indicate the columns to refer and not all. If you use Macro Recorder then it will give output like below:

`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$1800").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 7, 8), _
        Header:=xlYes`

What needs to be adjusted is last row which can be taken from the code you have found on the web.

Comment: It ran and a large proportion of duplications were deleted when I changed the Array to G (Email addresses) but when I started to look through a lot of duplications remained without any differences in the data, for example, I'd expect capitalisation to cause an issue but it wasn't present.

Comment: Excel's Remove Duplicates function is not case sensitive i.e. `batch`, `Batch` or `BATCH` are all duplicates. If it is not removing them that means one of the cell will be having some extra invisible characters.